# Wanting to stay in Direct Query mode, but Merging with INNER JOIN forces Import mode

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to merge two tables in Power BI Power Query Editor.  The data mart uses a "partition-view" partitioning method.  The first "table" in my merge is a view of 31 tables  containing a total of about 27 million rows.  So I want to keep the .pbix file in Direct Query mode.

Inspecting the "Native Query" property after performing my two merges, I see that Power Query Editor has created a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` for each merge.  The documentation for [Table.NestedJoin()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-nestedjoin) explains this:

> By default, a left outer join is performed if a joinKind is not specified.

Changing joinKind to INNER, either through the M code or through the Merge dialog behind the "Edit Settings" option for that step (which, of course, just generates M), causes the file to start using Import mode.

I have been looking for a web page or site that lists which M functions or options force a file into Import mode, but have not yet found that information.

Can the merge be configured to use an `INNER JOIN` in a way that will cause the file to remain in Direct Query mode?  It seems like it should be possible since it's such a minor change to the SQL Power Query is generating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general solution to a PQ transformation "breaking the fold" is to use SQL directly in [Value.NativeQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/native-query-folding#use-valuenativequery-function) to force the operation to run on the back-end as part of the first query step.

> The first "table" in my merge is a view of 31 tables containing a total of about 27 million rows.

That sounds really problematic for DirectQuery.  Using DirectQuery on top of complex transformations is, at best, complex.

27 million rows is not that many for Power BI, and you might be able to aggregate the results so you don't import that many, or use [Incremental Refresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/incremental-refresh-overview) to speed up refresh.

Comment: The table with 27 million rows is a SQL view, not a Power BI object.  From the Power Query perspective, it's one thing - not complex.  Sorry for the confusion.  I was just trying to include some mention of scale.  So are you saying that in order to use an `INNER JOIN` in Power Query and not have the process switch into Import mode I must write SQL?

Comment: There _may_ be a way to make that work if both tables are from SQL.  But the _general_ solution is to push the join to SQL.

Comment: I'm guessing based on you claiming to work for Microsoft and having 81.9k rep that this is the correct answer, so I'll mark it as such.  It doesn't feel like a good answer, though.  It seems odd that Power BI can't figure out how to send a simple `INNER JOIN` syntax to the database server.